# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 error

Tags: python, gcc, discord.py

Hey there I'm currently trying to help a host resolve an issue. The issue we getting is `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1` we have tried installing the gcc compiler `apt-get install python3-dev` however it seems to be already installed.

Error:

```
I/usr/include/python3.7m -c multidict/_multidict.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/multidict/_multidict.o -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -fno-strict-aliasing
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-bu65o7vu/multidict/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-c0gfiuzu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-bu65o7vu/multidict/
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Seán's Discord Bot:~/$
```

Weirdest t part is that gcc is installed
[image]

[image]

They use a container based system (docker) and need to find a way to implement it per-container.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to C++ ?

Comment: the tag has been removed.

Comment: This may be helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/428220/cant-run-make-gcc-command-not-found